# Generate JSON from java for jsTree

Tags: struts2

I am creating a jstree with JSON data in struts 2. I want to generate JSON data into action and pass to the JSP means for creating the tree. But I cant understand **how to pass JSON from Action class to JSP** and create jstree.
Please anybody provide me sample code for developing jstree from JSON in struts 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the struts2-json-plugin.  You can find numerous examples for using this plugin here on SO (I wrote a couple just search for them) and also here : http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html

Simply with the struts2-conventions-plugin and the struts2-json-plugin you would only need to place a struts2 action in a package that contains the word action.

ie: /somePackageStructure/action/MyAction.java

Now if you where to write http://myhost/my-action

You would get a json result (assuming you set up your action with the correct annotation or correct struts.xml, which is all explained in the previous link, or a search here).

How the json gets produced is quite simple. What ever you have getters for are seriallized into json.  What ever getters are exposed by those objects are also serialized in turn, also maps and lists are serialized as you would expect for json.

Note:  "how to pass JSON from Action class to JSP" you probably meant to say:  "How do I retrieve json from struts2 from a loaded page".  Because what you'll need to do is create an action to load your page (with your jstree), this page on the client will then need to make calls to retrieve the data that it needs.

If you have not worked with this plugin I would recommend entering the url into chrome, it will show a json result directly (If you're familiar with firebug that too is an excellent tool). Then create a page that displays something asynchronously when pressing a button. Then you'll be in a position to tackle this issue.

For getting started with the client side in using json and jquery this link helped me greatly: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You can generate JSON using the classes found on http://json.org/java/.
The pass the resulting String as a page scoped variable to the view and use it as you need.